# Maven build error on upgrading to new Spring Boot version

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a Maven Spring Boot project running within STS which builds fine:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Updating the Spring Boot's version in the above to **1.3.0.M4** results in:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.0.M4 from/to IWS_Repo (https://build-devtools.fw.net/artifactory/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 18, column 10
```

I tried it both in STS and on the command line: same error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Spring Boot releases, Spring Boot milestones aren't published to Maven Central. They are only published to repo.spring.io.

To upgrade from 1.2.5.RELEASE (which is available from Maven Central) to 1.3.0.M4 (which isn't), you'll need to add some extra configuration to your pom so that Maven knows to look in repo.spring.io's milestone repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Andy, would you happen to know some good reading materials on how the low level resolution of the certificates on which Maven stumbles (??) when the correct repo is not provided takes place?  Thanks!!

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are having certificate issues with your repository:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path
```

https://build-devtools.fw.net/artifactory/repo/

Try going directly to Maven Central :> http://repo1.maven.org/maven/

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: why does the certificate suddenly gets invalid when I update a parent?

Comment: share your entire pom.xml file.